# Comportamento de Spinners com dados do banco no Ciclo de vida

Tags: java, android, mobile

Eu tenho 3 Spinners dentro de um Fragment, o problema que estou tendo é quando giro a tela do Tablet e a tela se reconstrói, dessa forma os Spinners são zerados.

O primeiro Spinner vem do banco, dependendo da seleção do primeiro Spinner o segundo é preenchido e assim acontece com o terceiro Spinner quando escolho o segundo.

Eu já trato os dados, pois ao selecionar o item ele já salva no banco, porém, ao girar a tela tenho os problemas descritos em cima, segue um método que uso para mostrar o item salvo mesmo saindo da tela...

```
public void setSpinnerSelection(Spinner spinner, Adapter adapter, String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        String comparar = adapter.getItem(i).toString();
        if (comparar.equals(text)) {
            spinner.setSelection(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Notei algo estranho também, é comum quando o fragment é reconstruído ele executa o que tem dentro desse metodo do Spinner? "setOnItemSelectedListener", percebi que é exatamente isso o "gargalo".

Em resumo, queria saber uma forma inteligente de se trabalhar com o ciclo de vida do fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri como resolver esse problema...

Basta usar o setOnTouchListener do Spinner...

```
    spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Marca como selecionado.
            chave = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Depois de torna a chave VERDADEIRA, basta usar assim...

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (chave) {
            //Instrução...

            }
    }
```

Dessa maneira, mesmo que o Fragment ou Activity reconstrua, os valores se manter...

Answer (score 1):

Você deve fazer o *override* do método `onSaveInstanceState` e guardar os índices dos itens seleccionados de cada *spinner*.
Mais tarde, quando o *fragment* for recriado, poderá obter esses valores através do *Bundle* passado ao método `onActivityCreated`.

Será qualquer coisa do género:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    bundle.putLong("indice1", spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition());
    bundle.putLong("indice2", spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition());
    bundle.putLong("indice3", spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition());

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's state
        int index1 = savedInstanceState.getLong("indice1");
        int index2 = savedInstanceState.getLong("indice2");
        int index3 = savedInstanceState.getLong("indice3");

    }
}
```